# .NET 4 Deserialization issue: Illegal call to the reserved method

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, callstack

On some, but not all, machines when we try to deserialize some XML using (written in C#) `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)`
we get a kind of security related error described in the error message and stack trace below. The exception is thrown by the assembly that gets generated by .NET when serializing/deserializing.
In the stack trace below, `AggregateElement` derives from `Element`.
We haven't had any problems with .NET 3.5 and our code hasn't changed since we've upgraded to .NET 4
Does anyone have any ideas on what and why this is?

> Error: Illegal call to the reserved method 'Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSheet.Read53_AggregateElement()' from 'Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSheet.Read72_Element()'.
>
> Call Stack Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSheet.Read53_AggregateElement(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
>
> at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSheet.Read72_Element(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
>
> at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSheet.Read74_Section(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
>
> at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSheet.Read70_SubForm(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
>
> at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSheet.Read72_Element(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
>
> at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSheet.Read74_Section(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
>
> at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSheet.Read70_SubForm(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
>
> at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSheet.Read92_Sheet(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
>
> at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSheet.Read93_Sheet()
>
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
>
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>
> at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.InvokeReader(XmlMapping mapping, XmlReader xmlReader, XmlDeserializationEvents events, String encodingStyle)
>
> at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
>
> at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)

Comment: Could you isolate the problem into a simple console application with the involved classes and XML?

Comment: It is not a .NET exception message.  Bad translation?  Your own code generating it?

Comment: Did you recompile the code to target the .NET 4 framework, or is it the same binary you are using on both the .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 machines?